# opening Python scripts with spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am using anaconda and spyder as well as MacOS X Yosemite.

How can I make spyder the default program to open python scripts? When I just click on a script it is opened with TextEdit. When I click on open with I cannot choose spyder.

It is bothering to open spyder and then browse to the correct script.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your script -> Get Info -> then 'open with' in the combobox choose 'other' then locate the binary you want. Once you have chosen your binary click on 'change all'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not thought about searching for the correct path. It still does not work since I cannot choose the spyder app after I found it.