# Opening Python files by default with Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I installed Anaconda 4.1 for OS X and would like to set up my mac to open Python files using Spyder by default.

This question was asked last year by Glostas, [opening Python scripts with spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208073/opening-python-scripts-with-spyder) I tried the solution given to him and (like him at that time) it didn't work for me either.

That solution given is: choose a python file, then  Ctr+enter, "get info", "open with", choose the Spyder app. The problem I have is that there is no Spyder app; only the Anaconda Navigator app shows up.

Have somebody figured this out?

Comment: 'Spyder exe'?? If it's really called like this, no wonder that it can't open the file... What extension does your Python file have? It should be `file_name.py`

Comment: the python file extension is py. The spyder executable file is the one that appears in gray, so I can't choose it. This happens in Finder, when  I am in the "open with" option for the .py file... is it clearer now?

Comment: it was clear from the beginning. I was asked no whether the Spyder executable is a Windows executable (`.exe`) or a Mac OS one (`.app`)? You've written 'the Spyder exe appears frayed out', hence the question.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I'll edit the post now